# Disable BAD/Discard file log on SQL Loader

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

Is there a way to prevent sqlloader from creating either the BAD file or the DISCARD file or both?

I read in a forum that setting the BAD parameter to NUL or NULL does that, but it doesn't seem to work. Something like:

```
sqlldr control=CONTROL.ctl data=DATA.txt bad=NUL
```

This ends up creating a file called NUL.bad (or NULL.bad depending on how you spell it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Discard file should be optional, based on a discard predicate / discard parameter, but the Bad file is not an optional file - if you get rows rejected when loading, it will generate the file.

You could try send bad to the null depending (/dev/null in unix, NUL windows), did you set the right one for your OS?

Comment: Let me do a quick test and let you know how it went, I'm running it on linux BTW.

Comment: I never thought on pointing the file to the null device, works like a charm, thanks!